# JQUERY - Moving Selected Checkboxes to Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

could really use some help right about now! I'm brand new to javascript and am totally stuck. I would REALLY appreciate someone taking the time to help me out here with some javascript.

I'm creating a mobile app using JQUERY and PhoneGap. I have a "create your own" ToDo list feature. Basically someone selects the options on one page and then they are added to the ToDo list which is another page.

Here's some example HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="CreateChecklist">
<div ="header">
<div class="logo"></div>

</div>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>ToDo Checklist</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="checklist1" id="checklist1">
            <h3> Support Network </h3> 
         <p><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" name="checklist1" class="checklist2">

          <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_0" class="checklistA"      `enter code here`value="1" />

          <label for="checklist1_0">Create and mobilize support network</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_1" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_1">Set up meeting to discuss intervention logistics</label>

         <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_2" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_2">Assign a "detail person"</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_3" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_3">Designate the Intervention Facilitator</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_4" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_4">Make clear to not alert the person of concern</label>

              <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_22" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_22">Chair person creates an "opening" and "closing" dictation</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="checklist1" id="checklist1_24" class="checklistA" value="1" />
          <label for="checklist1_24">Create a list of personal support options (Al-Anon, therapy, etc)</label>


          </fieldset>
```

After the person has selected their checkboxes they click the button:

```
<a href="#ToDoChecklist" id="add">
<button>Submit</button></a>
```

I then need the selected checklists to be added to the other page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="ToDoChecklist">
<div ="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>

</div>
<div data-role="header">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" name="checklist2" class="checklist2" id="checklist2">


    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<h3> Content </h3>
</div><a href="#TakingAction">
<div data-role="footer">
 <h1>Back - Taking Action</h1> 
 </div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know theres no way to "move" elements from the current page to one that is yet to be loaded in javascript (without having some sort of callback on the jquery changePage method). instead consider passing the information in the

```
 href="#ToDOChecklist&checkbox1=selected&checkbox2=selected"
```

then use this information the populate the checkboxes in the new page

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll check in to the changePage method. That may be just what I'm looking for.